# Issue with ra-data-graphql with react-admin 2.0.0 and apolloclient 2.0

Tags: admin-on-rest

I'm using react-admin/aor 2.0.0-beta2 with ra-data-graphql with the instructions [here](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/c7bbcbd312a1c9d4b81b394ccaf19ba9d1eede9f/packages/ra-data-graphql/README.md)

and I see `TypeError: Cannot read property 'link' of undefined`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import buildGraphQLProvider from 'ra-data-graphql';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { Admin, Resource, Delete } from 'react-admin';
import { createNetworkInterface } from 'react-apollo';
import { PostCreate, PostEdit, PostList } from './posts';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import { createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';
import NotFound from './NotFound';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: 'light', // "light" or "dark" themes
  },
});

buildGraphQLProvider({
        clientOptions: {
//              uri: 'https://api.graph.cool/simple/v2/graphcool_id', ...otherApolloOptions 
                uri: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql'
        }
});

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { dataProvider: null };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        buildGraphQLProvider()
            .then(dataProvider => this.setState({ dataProvider }));
    }

    render() {
        const { dataProvider } = this.state;

        if (!dataProvider) {
            return <div>Loading</div>;
        }

        return (
            <Admin catchAll={NotFound} theme={theme} title="Private Admin" dashboard={Dashboard} dataProvider={dataProvider}>
                <Resource name="Post" list={PostList} edit={PostEdit} create={PostCreate} remove={Delete} />
            </Admin>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

I'm new to nodejs and reactjs and was wondering what changes are needed to get this to work with a graphql server endpoint

```
{
  "name": "ra-beta2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-client-preset": "^1.0.8",
    "graphql": "^0.12.3",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.7.0",
    "ra-data-graphql": "2.0.0-beta2",
    "ra-data-json-server": "^2.0.0-beta2",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-admin": "2.0.0-beta2",
    "react-apollo": "^2.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

- UPDATE1: complete App.js code
- UPDATE2: added versions of dependencies from `package.json`
- UPDATE3: added a ra-data-graphql-simple code based on example

  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import buildGraphQLProvider from 'ra-data-graphql-simple';
  import { Admin, Resource, Delete } from 'react-admin';
  import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';

  import { PostCreate, PostEdit, PostList } from './posts';

  const client = new ApolloClient();

  class App extends Component {
      constructor() {
          super();
          this.state = { dataProvider: null };
      }
      componentDidMount() {
          buildGraphQLProvider({ clientOptions: { uri: 'http://localhost:3000' }})
              .then(dataProvider => this.setState({ dataProvider }));
      }

  ```
  render() {
      const { dataProvider } = this.state;

      if (!dataProvider) {
          return <div>Loading</div>;
      }

      return (
          <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
              <Resource name="Post" list={PostList} edit={PostEdit} create={PostCreate} remove={Delete} />
          </Admin>
      );
  }
  ```

  }

  export default App;

Here is the exception -

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'link' of undefined
new ApolloClient
src/aor/ra-beta2-graphql/node_modules/apollo-client/ApolloClient.js:24
  21 | var _this = this;
  22 | this.defaultOptions = {};
  23 | this.resetStoreCallbacks = [];
> 24 | var link = options.link, cache = options.cache, _a = options.ssrMode, ssrMode = _a === void 0 ? false : _a, _b = options.ssrForceFetchDelay, ssrForceFetchDelay = _b === void 0 ? 0 : _b, connectToDevTools = options.connectToDevTools, _c = options.queryDeduplication, queryDeduplication = _c === void 0 ? true : _c, defaultOptions = options.defaultOptions;
  25 | if (!link || !cache) {
  26 |     throw new Error("\n        In order to initialize Apollo Client, you must specify link & cache properties on the config object.\n        This is part of the required upgrade when migrating from Apollo Client 1.0 to Apollo Client 2.0.\n        For more information, please visit:\n          https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/setup.html\n        to help you get started.\n      ");
  27 | } 

./src/App.js
src/aor/ra-beta2-graphql/src/App.js:8
   5 |  
   6 | import { PostCreate, PostEdit, PostList } from './posts';
   7 |  
>  8 | const client = new ApolloClient();
   9 |  
  10 | class App extends Component {
  11 |     constructor() {
```

Answer (score 0):

We haven't updated the instructions yet. Sorry about that. But here, you're mixing two approaches.

You can either:

1. Create your own client and pass it to `buildGraphQLProvider` as a `client` option:

`buildGraphQLProvider({ client: myClient });`.

2. Let `buildGraphQLProvider` build it for you, eventually passing options to customize it:

`buildGraphQLProvider({ clientOptions: { uri: 'https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/graphcool_id', ...otherApolloOptions } });`

Please check the ApolloClient documentation about available options.

I'll update the documentation on our side ASAP

Comment: Thank for the response: I still get `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'link' of undefined` with the second approach. 

It would be great if the documentation is detailed :) The apolloclient 2.0 requires link to be passed which is missing from the buildGraphQLProvider

Comment: Can you update your question with the current code you are using, along with the versions of every `react-admin` packages you're using ?

Comment: Along with the versions of every react-admin packages you're using ?

Comment: Can you also post the full error with its stack. I'm struggling to reproduce your issue. This is working on the sample app

Comment: No the demo app which uses `ra-data-graphql-simple`. But they just expose the `buildGraphQLProvider` from `ra-data-graphql` anyway

Comment: Tried with `ra-data-graphql-simple` example with `json-graphql-server` and I get the same exception. fyi, im new to nodejs :) I've updated with new code and the trace in detail